# Spring Test DB Unit: Failed to load Application Context

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test, spring-test-dbunit

Below is the error I encountered while running Spring-Test-DBUnit. Have you encountered the same issue when doing integration test. Do you have any idea on how can this be resolved? Thanks.

```
testCreatePerson(some project file): Failed to load ApplicationContext
testHomePage(some project file): Failed to load ApplicationContext
testSameOriginXFrameOptions(some project file): Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

I am using spring mvc to create a web project and want to use spring test dbunit.

```
@Controller
public class PersonController
{
@RequestMapping( value = "/add-person", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ResponseEntity<String> addPerson( @Validated @ModelAttribute PersonDB person, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Principal principal ) throws Exception
    {
        handleValidationError( bindingResult );
        String username = userAccountUtility.getUsernameFrom( principal );
        personService.add( emil, username );
        personConnectionManager.updatePersonConnectionMap( emil, username );

        return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK );
    }
}
```

/*******************************************/ BaseTestConfig

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import com.person.utils.OperatingSystem;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan( {"com.person", "com.person.commons"} )
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource( "classpath:application.properties" )
public class BaseTestConfig
{

    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL_LINUX = "db.url.linux";
    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL_WINDOWS = "db.url.windows";
    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";


    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private OperatingSystem operatingSystem;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        String databaseUrl = PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL_LINUX;

        if( operatingSystem.isWindows() )
        {
            databaseUrl = PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL_WINDOWS;
        }

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName( env.getRequiredProperty( PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER ) );
        dataSource.setUrl( env.getRequiredProperty( databaseUrl ) );
        dataSource.setUsername( env.getRequiredProperty( PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME ) );
        dataSource.setPassword( env.getRequiredProperty( PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD ) );

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver()
    {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix( "/WEB-INF/pages/" );
        resolver.setSuffix( ".jsp" );
        resolver.setViewClass( JstlView.class );
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

/*******************************************/ SpringTest

```
//packages and imports
@WebAppConfiguration("src/test/resources")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BaseTestConfig.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@DatabaseSetup("dataset/empty-person-dataset.xml")
public class EmilInstanceCreationTest {

    @Resource
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .build();
    }

    private static final String firstname = "jane";
    public static final String lastname = "cruz";
    public static final String midllename = "garner";

    @Autowired
    private PersonController personController;

    @Autowired
    private PersonDB person;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initContext() {
        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
        System.setProperty("keycloak.configurationFile", "keycloak.json");
    }


    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("dataset/add-person-dataset.xml")
    public void testCreatePersonInstance() throws Exception {
        BindingResult mockBindingResult = mock(BindingResult.class);
        when(mockBindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(false);
        personController.addPerson(person, mockBindingResult, principals.create(firtstname, firstname, lastname));
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you providde more information? Like the test your're trying to run...

Comment: please se additional info above.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. it was because the application.properties file was not included in the test folders.